# Is there a Mathematica resource to work with Geometric Algebra?

Tags: packages

I've not been able to find a package which will deal with Geometric Algebra. Perhaps somebody can help?

Comment: What are some of the capabilities you are looking for in such a package?

Comment: Basically the more elementary functions for geometry, such as outer and geometric products

Comment: Check out https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/BySubject/Mathematics/Geometry/

Comment: Thank you all, Syed, E. Chan-Lopez and Bill Watts. I obtained many times more than I had expected. It will take some time to digest, though.

Answer (score 2):

Check in the following link: [GeometricAlgebra Package](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/index/sort/newest/keyword/Clifford%20algebra/has_examples/false/has_download/false).

Comment: This link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the available resources for CGA are listed below.

Mathematica CGA package from Kyushu University: [github](https://github.com/KyushuUniversityMathematics/MathematicaCGA),
[paper](https://easychair.org/publications/open/8jDf)

Peter Joot's work:
[github](https://github.com/peeterjoot/mathematica),
webpage with [notebooks](http://peeterjoot.com/mathematica/),
[blog](http://peeterjoot.com/tag/geometric-algebra-for-engineers/)

From Cornell University:
[webpage](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02513) (with paper and code)

**Other resources**:

Chris Doran's [blog](http://geometry.mrao.cam.ac.uk/2020/06/euclidean-geometry-and-geometric-algebra/), [resources](https://bivector.net/index.html)

Dr.-Ing. Dietmar Hildenbrand's [webpage](http://www.gaalop.de/dhilden/), youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cWGV2qaBHo)